Reference request concerning Frege on truth?
According to my memory, Frege wrote an article or a book where he in the beginning states something to the effect that truth is the subject matter of logic. What is the name of the text, if any?

Frege starts his (late, 1918) essay Der Gedanke: eine logische Untersuchung with these statements:

Wie das Wort „schön“ der Ästhetik und „gut“ der Ethik, so weist „wahr“ der Logik die Richtung. Zwar haben alle Wissenschaften Wahrheit als Ziel; aber die Logik beschäftigt sich noch in ganz anderer Weise mit ihr. Sie verhält sich zur Wahrheit etwa so wie die Physik zur Schwere oder zur Wärme. Wahrheiten zu entdecken, ist Aufgabe aller Wissenschaften: der Logik kommt es zu, die Gesetze des Wahrseins zu erkennen.


Like the word "beautiful" in esthetics and "good" in ethics, the word "true" indicates the target of logic. Even though all sciences aim at truth, logic treats it in a very different way. Logic relates to truth more or less like physics to weight or warmth. To discover truths is the task of all sciences: but it's up to logic, to get to know the laws of being true.

[my quick and dirty translation]
The essay then immediately dives into a criticism of psychologism (the idea that logical laws can be derived from or justified in reference to psychological phenomena). And he then demarcates logic from psychology:

Um jedes Mißverständnis auszuschließen und die Grenze
zwischen Psychologie und Logik nicht verwischen zu lassen, weise ich der Logik die Aufgabe zu, die Gesetze
des Wahrseins zu finden, nicht die des Fürwahrhaltens oder Denkens. In den Gesetzen des Wahrseins wird die
Bedeutung des Wortes „wahr“ entwickelt.


In order to exclude all misunderstanding and to not let the boundary between psychology and logic fade away, I assign to logic the task of finding the laws of being true, not those of holding-something-to-be-true or of thinking [as psychological, empirical process]. In the laws of being-true the meaning of the word "true" will be developed.

It's remarkable how plain and down-to-earth Frege's writing style is (despite the occasional professorial tone from up high as in "I assign to logic the task..."), and how extremely clear his thinking. Rather than reading any secundary literature, anyone should really first read this essay, and then any of this other writings.

Gottlob Frege, considered by many to be the father of the analytical tradition, is known for a number of views and works on truth and his formalization of symbolic logic. His Begriffsschrift published in 1879 may be his most famous work, but his work is extensive. In fact, others like Michael Dummett have written extensively just on Frege's extensive work on the interconnection of logic, mathematics, and language and Frege's logicism. Besides the WP link above, if you're looking for a particular work one of the best places to start would the the SEP's article Gottlob Frege. It has an extensive bibliography and is an excellent introduction into his works. Lykke til!

General information on Frege as this, which is known by most people in the philosophical community, cannot amount to an appropriate answer to my precise reference request.

Precise reference request? lol I think you mistranslated "precise". I'm glad mudskipper was able to help you out.

@FrodeAlfsonBjørdal In JD's defense, I would say, it might not have been completely clear from your question if you had this background knowledge :)

@mudskipper Danke für deine Worte, mein Herr, aber ich feiere die Worte was kann man nicht zerstören... ; )

@JD - Du feierst? Fürchtest, vielleicht? Weihnachten - das wird gefeiert.  Frohe Weihnachten! :)
